# get header data and object from RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, http-headers

I'm trying to get some authentication values from the response header and also get the filled object. But my problem is, that I get either the header values or the filled object like shown in the example here.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String requestJson = "{ \"identifier\": \"username\", \"password\": \"pw\" } ";

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.add("KEY","apikey");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestJson,headers);

Login login = restTemplate.postForObject("https://url.com",entity, Login.class);
```

or

```
HttpEntity<String> response = template.exchange("https://url.com", HttpMethod.POST, entit, Login.class);

String resultString = response.getBody();
HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
```

Is there a way to do the response => object exchange later?
Or a fully different way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using this code:

```
ResponseEntity<Login> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, Login.class);
Login login = response.getBody();
HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
```

So my result is the filled Login object in login and my Headers are in headers.